# Highlight NSView on Rollover/Click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

Upon rolling over or clicking on an NSView, how can I update the view so that I can change the colour and other properties of view? It's the redrawing of the view which is the key to what I need to do, I already have a subclass created.

Comment: How are you keeping references to your views? Are you by any chance using a collection view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for mouse events and do appropriate actions inside them.

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    //draw rollover
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    //draw normal
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    //draw selected
}

-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    //draw normal
}
```

Comment: @alexgray: What doesn't work?  The methods aren't called? You need to  make sure your window subclass conforms to the `NSWindowDelegate`.

Comment: -mouseDown and -mouseUp should work like expected. However, -mouseEntered and -mouseExited need trackingAreas to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190700/388412