# mouseEntered and mouseExited not called in NSImageView SubClass

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimageview

I created a subclass of `NSImageView` to capture `mouseEntered`  and `mouseExited` events.
But only `mouseUp` and `mouseDown` events are getting called. How to capture the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events in `NSImageView` subclass?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If You want to use `mouseEntered:` and `mouseExited:` You need to use `NSTrackingArea`. Here is reference [NSTrackingArea Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html).

**Example:**

```
//Add this to Your imageView subclass

-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSLog(@"Mouse entered");
}

-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"Mouse exited");
}

-(void)updateTrackingAreas
{ 
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    if(trackingArea != nil) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
        [trackingArea release];
    }

    int opts = (NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways);
    trackingArea = [ [NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:[self bounds]
                                                 options:opts
                                                   owner:self
                                                userInfo:nil];
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea];
}
```

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Or it is the reality of having a complex view hierarchy and not wanting to invoke potentially hundreds of thousands of methods when the user merely slides the pointer over a hunk of UI.    This is the age old **Never poll, always pull.**

Comment: Bingoo, Worked like charm

Comment: @Edward What? Pull vs. Poll?  No;  **Significantly** more relevant in 2016 than 1988.  In 1988, devices were all powered from the wall.  In 2016, the majority of devices are powered by a battery and *polling* is devastating to battery life.

Comment: @bbum just realized you work at the mothership. I bow.

Comment: @Edward I've been at this ObjC thing for a long, long time. :)

Comment: "Invoke hundereds and thousands of methods when the user merely slides the pointer"? What is there to invoke if no callback function is defined? C# has the exact same callback for all controls, and you don't have to setup weird insider snippets of code, buried inside tones of documentation. If you've defined a callback for a control it gets invoked, otherwise nothing. As simple as that. I don't get what's so different in OS X stack that makes this necessary.

Comment: Few things missing from this solution, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979639/mouseexited-isnt-called-when-mouse-leaves-trackingarea-while-scrolling

Comment: Why are we running this code everytime we updateTrackingAreas()? Would it be better to put in the init() of the NSImageView?

Comment: @RicardoAnjos updateTrackingAreas is the appropriate place for this in general. For example, if this were somewhere earlier (e.g. in init) it wouldn't be properly recreated when the view was moved or resized.

Answer (score 15):

Swift 4 version of [Justin Boo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188034/mouseentered-and-mouseexited-not-called-in-nsimageview-subclass/11190700#11190700)

```
override func updateTrackingAreas() {
    super.updateTrackingAreas()

    for trackingArea in self.trackingAreas {
        self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }
    
    let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeAlways]
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}
```

Comment: Can/should we not edit existing answers to update them to the latest version of a language?

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3** Version of [@Justin Boo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190700/819340)'s answer:

```swift
private var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?

override func updateTrackingAreas() {
    super.updateTrackingAreas()

    if let trackingArea = self.trackingArea {
        self.removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
    }

    let options: NSTrackingAreaOptions = [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .activeAlways]
    let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: self.bounds, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
    self.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)
}
```

Comment: why is super not being called? it is in justin's solution

Comment: @CharltonProvatas, you're right, it was a mistake. The official docs also say that it should be called. My answer has now been updated.

Answer (score 4):

C# Xamarin version of Justin Boo's answer

```
public override void UpdateTrackingAreas ()
{
    base.UpdateTrackingAreas ();

    foreach (var item in TrackingAreas ()) {
        RemoveTrackingArea (item);
    }

    var options = NSTrackingAreaOptions.MouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingAreaOptions.ActiveAlways;

    var trackingArea = new NSTrackingArea (this.Bounds, options, this, null);

    AddTrackingArea (trackingArea);
}
```