# mouseEntered and mouseExited with SKSpriteNode

Tags: event-handling, sprite-kit

How do we get `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` to work with say a `SKSpriteNode`?

The documentation mentions something called a tracking rectangle however there is no more information on it.

This seems partly relevant, however it cannot be fully used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11190700/129202

Comment: how have you set up the project ? I cannot create a Sprite Kit game for mac

Comment: Sprite Kit is part of iOS and OS X.

Comment: so just create a cocoa app and go from there i guess?

Comment: SK works (again) on OS X in Xcode 5.0.1 GM seed. You can implement these methods and forward them to registered delegates. See Kobold Kit for example http://koboldkit.com

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that stick game on kobold is cool, be a great challenge to try and make that on SK.